# Doubling measure implies that the measure of any ball $B_{\lambda\delta}$ is bounded by the measure of a smaller ball $B_\delta$ times a factor

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\mu$ a borel measure in $X$ such that any open ball in $(X,d)$ has a positive and finite measure. Then $\mu$ is called *doubling* if there exists a positive constant $C$ such that for any open ball $B_\delta$ of radius $\delta>0$:
$$\mu(B_{2\delta})\leq C \mu(B_\delta).$$
I am trying to show that "for any $\lambda>0$ there exists a constant $C_\lambda>1$ such that $\mu(B_{\lambda\delta})\leq C_\lambda \mu(B_\delta)$"

The case $0<\lambda\leq 1$ is trivial. Consider the case $\lambda>1$ and let us define be the decreasing sequence $(\lambda_n)$ given by $\lambda_n=1+2^{1-n}\lambda$. Then the balls $\{B_{\lambda_n\delta}\}$ is a decreasing sequence of measurable set such that $B_{\lambda_1\delta}=B_\delta$ has a finite measure. This implies:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_{\lambda_n\delta})=\mu\Big(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}B_{\lambda_n\delta}\Big)=\mu(B_\delta) \qquad\qquad\qquad (\star)$$
On the other hand, we have that $B_{\delta\lambda}=B_{2^{n-1}(\lambda_n-1)}$  for any $n\geq 1$. Hence, by hypothesis:
$$\mu(B_{\delta\lambda})\leq C^n\mu(B_{(\lambda_n-1)\delta})$$
The above relation together with $\mu(B_{(\lambda_n-1)\delta})\leq \mu(B_{\lambda_n\delta})$ implies:
$$\mu(B_{\delta\lambda})\leq C^n\mu(B_{(\lambda_n-1)\delta})\leq C^n \mu(B_{\lambda_n\delta})$$
Taking the limit $n\to \infty$ in the above inequality yields:
$$\mu(B_{\delta\lambda})\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} C^n\mu(B_{\lambda_n\delta})$$

From $(\star)$ we know that the factor $\mu(B_{\lambda_n\delta})$ converges to $\mu(B_\delta)$. However, I am not able to prove that the product $C^n\mu(B_{\lambda_n\delta})$ also converges to $C_\lambda \mu(B_\delta)$ for some $C_\lambda>1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some of the right idea, but I don’t think you need to take any limits. For each $\lambda >1$ let $N$ be the unique integer such that $2^{N-1} < \lambda \leqslant 2^N$. Then $$ \mu(B_{\lambda\delta}) \leqslant \mu(B_{2^N\delta}) \leqslant C^N\mu(B_\delta)$$ which proves the result with $C_\lambda:= C^N$.